# Issue in choosing time(minute) from DatePickerIOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm facing a problem in DatePickerIOS in react-native. I'm trying to choose minute from picker but it gives me like this: `11:04`. When I choose `hour` it choose properly. I also attach image for this issue. The code is showing below.

```
_selectFromTime = () => {
    this.setState({
       showFromTimePicker: !this.state.showFromTimePicker
    })
}
_onFromTimeChange(fromTime) {
    let getFromTime = moment(fromTime).format('HH:MM');
    this.setState({from_time: fromTime})
    this.setState({from_t: getFromTime})
}

render(){
  return(
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
       <TouchableOpacity 
        activeOpacity={0.8} 
        onPress={this._selectFromTime}
        style={s.flex_direction_row}
       >
         <Text style={s.detail_txtinput_drpdown}>
            {this.state.from_t}
         </Text>
         <Icon style={s.calendar_icon} name="md-clock" size={24} color="#00796b"/>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       {
         this.state.showFromTimePicker ?
            <DatePickerIOS
               date={this.state.from_time}
               onDateChange={(from_time)=>this._onFromTimeChange(from_time)}
               mode="time"
            />
       :
         null
       }
   </View>
);
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4ApC.png .

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use [`getMinutes()` on passed Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Date/getMinutes):

```
_onFromTimeChange(fromTime) {
    let getFromTime = moment(fromTime);
    this.setState({
      from_time: fromTime, 
      from_t: getFromTime
    })
}
```

and then:

```
this.state.from_time.getMinutes();
```

e.g:

```
const { from_time } = this.state;
const time = from_time.getHours() + ":" + from_time.getMinutes();

<Text style={s.detail_txtinput_drpdown}>
  {time}
</Text>
```

Comment: I put this and it gives me correct minutes but I want both hour and minute as per I displayed in above image.

Comment: @Riddhi well then maybe you can use it like in the edit ^